# Google App Engine: f:setPropertyActionListener with p:ajax

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces

once again the combination of PrimeFaces and GAE drives me crazy. Inside a `p:dataTable` I want to click a image, call a bean method and set a parameter. The method is called, but the parameter does not work. Here is a simplified example (without the table):

```
<h:form id="f1">
  <h:outputText id="text" value="#{testBean.index}"/>
  <h:graphicImage url="/images/cut.png">
    <p:ajax event="click" process="@this" update="text"
            actionListener="#{testBean.test}" >
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.index}" value="5" />
    </p:ajax>
  </h:graphicImage>
</h:form>
```

My `TestBean` looks like this:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean @ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable{
  private int index; // getter/setter

  @PostConstruct public void init() {
    index = 0;log.log(Level.WARNING, "@PostConstruct");}

  public void test(ActionEvent ae){
    log.log(Level.WARNING, "Index: "+index);}
}
```

In the Logs I see one `@PostConstruct` and after clicking the image always `Index: 0`

**Update** The value update problem may be discussed here [JSF GAE: Value Update Problem in managed bean method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361734)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about GAE, so I can't assume that it isn't somehow interfering with your code.  I don't necessarily think that the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is the appropriate tag to use for a `<p:ajax>` tag however.  I don't believe it accepts that.

Here is an example of how I implemented an ajax call to a viewscoped bean property using `<p:commandLink>` and an HTML `<span>` tag.

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{listUsers.toModify}" oncomplete="userEditDlg.show()"
    update="addEditForm:editGrid addEditGrid:passwordChange addEditGrid:passwordGrid">
    <f:param name="userId" value="#{user.userId}" />
    <span class="ui-icon icoCogEdit" style="padding-right: 1.5em;" />
</p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{listUsers.toDelete}" oncomplete="userDelDlg.show()"
    update="listUsersForm:dialogText">
    <f:param name="userId" value="#{user.userId}"/>
    <span class="ui-icon icoDelete" />
</p:commandLink>
```

I just set a CSS class to be a static image icon of my choosing, and then clicking on it would invoke a dialog.

Comment: Clarification: the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is only supported on parent components implementing `ActionSource`. The `<h:graphicImage>` doesn't. Interesting detail is however that when you use `<f:ajax>` instead of `<p:ajax>`, an exception is been thrown with exactly that message. The `<span>` can by the way also be replaced by the desired `<h:graphicImage>`. The `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` will by the way work equally fine instead of `<f:param>` inside a `<p/h:commandLink>`.

Comment: @BalusC, I wasn't aware of this and learned something new, but if you look closely you will see that the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is actually inside of the `<p:ajax>` tag, the indentation is screwy.  This is good information though.

Comment: A `<f:xxx>` can't be a child of another `<f:xxx>`. It will just be a child of the parentmost `UIComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the question with a problem of the value updates. I've encountered a similar issue a while ago working with _RichFaces_, but my searches don't point me to any solution for this.